# Why Visual Studio 2010 add 'fa.resx' insted 'fa-IR.resx' for resource file?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, globalization

why visual studio 2012 add 'fa' language name for resource file and don't add 'fa-IR' for the name of resource files, like visual studio 2008 ?

so my project that have 'fa-IR.resx' resource files has been corrupted, and when i switch

between language in design time,  layout of form don't change , because the 'fa.resx' file not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that the good people of Microsoft decided between 2008 and 2012 that Iran is default location for Farsi language, and so there is no need to state it specifically. But someone forgot to convert all the files appropriately in conversion wizard, and now you have a problem.

The problem should be solved if you change the project manually. Before doing any of this back up project and all the files in it. Just in case.

Open project file (.csproj) in some text editor like Notepad, and replace all fa-IR with fa. Replace fa-IR with fa in all source files. Rename all files that have fa-IR. This should be enough.

Comment: @user2477928 if this is the correct answer then mark it as correct by clicking on the hollow check mark. It's always nice to see reputation increased.